# Javascript: How to find sum of array for index range and push values into a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, reduce

```
start = [0, 1, 0]   //starting index
end = [1, 5, 5]  //ending index
main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How would one find the sum of an array, for the given index range, and push sum values into a new array?

Expected output:

```
[3, 20, 21]
```

Comment: I don't follow what exactly you need? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: let indexes = [1, 3];
let main = indexes.reduce((acc, cur)=>acc+array[cur],0); //i do not know how to iterate 3 times for indexes = [start[i], end[i]]

Answer (score 0):

Your question was super unclear... but i guess this is what you are looking for:

```js
var start = [0, 1, 0]   //starting index
var end = [1, 5, 5]  //ending index
var main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var result = []

for (var i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
  let x = start[i]
  let y = end[i]
  result[i] = 0
  for (;x <= y;) result[i] += main[x++]
}

console.log(result)
```

the code would be better to understand if instead of using two separate array you had eg:

```js
lookFor = [{
  start: 0,
  end: 1
}, { 
  start: 1,
  end: 5
}, { 
  start: 0,
  end: 5
}]
```

something else could be a 2D array of (start & end)

```js
sumUp = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 5],
  [0, 5]
]

// then you could at least write it as:
result = sumUp.map(([start end]) => {
  return main.slice(start, end).reduce(sumFn, 0)
})
```

or something like that...

but if you insist on having 2 different array you could also do:

```js
var start = [0, 1, 0]   //starting index
var end = [1, 5, 5]  //ending index
var main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

// then you could at least write it as:
var result = start.map((start, i) => 
  main.slice(start, end[i] + 1).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` methods as follows:

```js
const 
start = [0, 1, 0],   //starting index
end = [1, 5, 5],  //ending index
main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],

output = start.map(
    (s,i) => main.slice(s,end[i]+1).reduce(
        (sum,cur) => sum + cur, 0
    )
);

console.log( output );
```